# In Powermock, how do I express that I expect a static void method to be called?

Tags: junit, static, mocking, void, powermock

I’m using the PowerMock v 1.6.2 and JUnit 4.11.  How do I express that I expect a static void method to be called?  I have the following

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.mockStatic;
…
    mockStatic(SecurityContextHolder.class);
    expect(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()).andReturn(securityContext);
    expect(SecurityContextHolder.clearContext());
   replay(SecurityContextHolder.class);
```

But the second “expect” line is giving the compilation error, “The method expect(T) in the type EasyMock is not applicable for the arguments (void)”.  How do I express that I expect the static void method to be called?

Comment: for a `void` method you need to use , `expectLastCall(.....)` instead of 'expect'

Answer (score 0):

Void methods don't have return since they don't return any value. Try expectLastCall() instead